# Display ReCaptcha field after Joomla 3.7 user custom fields

Tags: registration, custom-field, joomla-3.7

I added some text custom fields to the user registration form. Joomla 3.7 allows users to easily add custom fields to various components, this is a nice feature. However I'm unable to figure out how to make the ReCaptcha field display after the custom fields. I have tried to place the Recaptcha plugin after the custom fields plugin however this does not seem to be allowed. Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

replace the form output with this code:

`<?php if ($field->type !== 'Captcha') : ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else :
    $captcha = '
    <div class="form-group">
          ' . $field->label . '
          <div class="controls">
              ' . $field->input . '
          </div>
    </div>
';
endif; ?>`

and, just before the submit, put `<?php echo $captcha; ?>`.